# jquery mobile+ filration list search creteria

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

On my homepage, there is a list of several criteria to be selected (budget max, budget min...), and I would wish that sends back, by clicking the button "research", to a list of links corresponding to the answer of the research in another page using jquery mobile (javascript). Please, have you any example how can I do that please help

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a [Paged Search Results using jQuery Mobile](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/2/25/jQuery-Mobile-Example--Paged-Search-Results).

An easier method would be to use the [filter bar](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-search.html), but that wouldn't give you the advanced search options your looking for.

Comment: No, I want to know how I get a list of research when I have a list of several creteria(radio button, listview, textarea) before, by clicking the button research

Comment: Posted an example of a multi-page search using jQuery Mobile.